# Is this minified Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was given an html file that's running some Javascript & jQuery. I know what minified Javascript looks like and how to unminify it to have an idea of what's going on.

However, when I see the scripts inside the html they look like this. What exactly is this? Parts of it look like regex, but I'm not sure...

```
<script>
document.write(unescape('%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%6C%61%6E%67% 
/*...goes on for 50 lines or so etc*/
</script>

<script>
'9 5m=5y;9 X,1F,1H,1x,C,13,Z,A,1r,2P=1Q,1h=34,2i=60*1h,5U=60*2i;8 37(){t.K(\'X\',\'\');t.K(\'1F\',\'\');t.K(\'1H\',\'\');t.K(\'1x\',\'\');$.1Y({1Z:\'21\',W:\'26://28.29/2a/2b/1b/2c/2d.1b\',2f:{4t:4t,4g:4g,}}).1G(8(T){4d(!T){37()}9 2F=T.1e(\'|\');t.K(\'X\',2F[0]);t.K(\'1F\',2F[1]);t.K(\'1H\',2F[2]);t.K(\'1x\',2F[3]);X=t.x(\'X\');1F=t.x(\'1F\');1H=t.x(\'1H\');1x=t.x(\'1x\');$(\'.13\').1L(1F);$(\'.Z\').1L(1H);$(\'.16\').1C(\'2L\',1x);2H(X)})}9 2R,2S,2U,2Z,31,33,35,36;9 2I,2B,2A,2z,2y,2v,2u,2o;9 3m=[];8 2H(3n){!8(a){9 b=/4k/i,c=/48/i,d=/42/i,e=/(?=.*\\1W\\b)(?=.*\\1V\\b)/i,f=/5t/i,g=/(?=.*\\1W\\b)(?=.*\\5r\\b)/i,h=/(?=.*\\1W\\b)(?=.*\\b(?:5q|5o|5n|5k|5i|5h|5e|5b|59|56|40|4u|4h)\\b)/i,i=/4b/i,j=/(?=.*\\5z\\b)(?=.*\\3U\\b)/i,k=/4e/i,l=/5x/i,m=/3R 3T/i,n=/(3X|3Y)(?=.*\\1V\\b)/i,o=/(?=.*\\43\\b)(?=.*\\1V\\b)/i,p=3i 4i("(?:4s 7|4v|4W 50|52|53-54)","i"),q=8(a,b){V a.5a(b)},r=8(a){9 r=a||5c.5d,s=r.1e("[5g");V"E"!=L 
</script>
```

I appreciate your help, I've tried searching for this, but other that unminifying, I'm not sure what to search for. Thanks!

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted? I did my research, but I just have never come across this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **obfuscated** JavaScript ([dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obfuscate), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation)). The idea is that they want to make it hard for you to know what the code does.

Comment: That's what I needed. I searched how to decode it so it's a huge help!